# How to do italic node labels with GraphViz dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot, italics

I'm trying to draw some graph using graphviz with dot. It works fine. However, I would like to set the font to italic for letters (a,b,c...). Here is my code:

```
digraph mygraph{
  node [shape=plaintext]
 "Ø" -> "{a}" 
 "Ø" -> "{b}" 
 "Ø" -> "{c}"
 "Ø" -> "{d}"
}
```

What should I do so that 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' would be in italics but not the '{' and '}'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try using the syntax for [Html-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and first define the node `a` with a label attribute:

```
a [label=<{<I>a</I>}>]
"Ø" -> a
```

Comment: Thanks but by doing this, the {a} is shown as an edge label rather than a node label. I want the node label to be in italics

Comment: You're right of course, I fixed the example - you'll have to first define the node with its attributes, and then define the edges.

Comment: When used in this way with `shape = circle`, the circle becomes an ellipse, and the double circle does not appear. This code: `q0 [label=<<I>q</I>0>]`, `node [shape = doublecircle]; q0;`, `node [shape = circle]; qi -> q0; q0  -> q0  [ label = "b" ];` does paint ellipses. Why is it so?